# Old sci fi short story about parents with 2 dimensional children

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Story was about parents with 2 dimensional child or children. Want to cure them but I think end up switching dimensions with children.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  We are more likely to be able to help you if you can give us some more details.  Was this a book?  Novella?  Short story?   About when did you read it?  Was it new then?  If a short story, was it in an anthology?  A magazine?  Can you give any more details about the story itself?  Even character names can help, if you remember any.

Comment: Flat Stanley? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_Stanley

Comment: May be Tomorrow's Child by Ray Bradbury.  A birth transporter beam puts the baby into an alternate dimension causing it to appear as a pyramid.   Parents eventually join it since a cure may not happen.  Was adapted for television as well.

Comment: This sounds ever so vaguely familiar -- but it does sound familiar, as a tongue-in-cheek science fiction story that is not Flat Stanley. Keep trying!

Comment: @lucasbachmann Yeah, "Tomorrow's Child" aka "The Shape of Things" is the first story I thought of too. As I recall, it's just one child, and not 2-dimensional., but I bet that's it. The story is available at the Internet Archive: https://archive.org/details/Thrilling_Wonder_Stories_v31n03_Standard_Feb_1948_cape1736/page/n46/mode/1up

Comment: If Ray Bradbury's "Tomorrow's Child" aka "The Shape of Things" is the correct answer, the question does not seem to be a duplicate, as far as I can tell. "The Shape of Things" was part of an **unaccepted** answer to [this old question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105424/young-adult-anthology-book-from-1970s-1980s) which was asking about an anthology. Maybe you should post an answer @lucasbachmann